# why does my Philips monitor come back on when I switch off?

Tags: display

When Iswitch my computer off,the monitor used to go to standby mode,but recently the monitor comes back on and displays the word aging.Everything works properly when I switch back on,so I am wondering if this is a problem with my Philips monitor.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these monitors but 'aging' sounds like it should be significant.

Comment: Sounds like planned obsolescence. What model is it?

Answer (score 0):

This was a mode for CRT monitors back in the day, is this a CRT? Has something to do with technicians doing color temp adjustments or some such thing. Though if it is LCD it may have a different use or meaning.

I think perhaps if you go into the monitor's menus and find the reset, or restore defaults setting, that might get rid of it. Without the exact model I couldn't tell you the path, but it is usually fairly easy to find on most monitors.